# My loop does not count the final indexes in my array

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I have created nested loops to loop through the `querySeq` array which is an array of 63 alphabetic characters. The `blockSize` variable equals to 12 so the `queryBlockSize` is 52. My goal is to extract words of length 12 out of these 63 single characters and put them in the `wordsSeq` array. The problem is that when the first loop reaches the final iteration (`i = 51`) and the inner loop should loop and make a word out of index 51 to 62, the loop does not create this word and skips this iteration. I can share the whole code if needed. Thank you in advance for the help.

```
int queryBlockSize = querySeq.size() - blockSize + 1; 
    char wordsSeq[queryBlockSize][blockSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < queryBlockSize; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < blockSize; j++){
            wordsSeq[i][j] = querySeq.at(i + j);
            cout << wordsSeq[i][j];
        } 
        cout << endl << endl;
        cout << "****************************************" << endl << endl << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Size of the wordSeq is: " << sizeof(wordsSeq)/sizeof(wordsSeq[0]) << endl << endl;
```

Comment: When `i=1` and `j=0`, what is `i+j`? And what should the index into `querySeq` be at this point?

Comment: when i=0 and j  goes from 0 to 11 to extact first word then a i becomes 1 and the inner loop makes the second word of length 12 starting from the i=1 and this process repeates until i becomes 51 and the inner loop should make the final 12 length word but the problem is it doesn't do this.

Comment: Your comparison on the `i` loop is `i < queryBlockSize`, i.e., `i < 51`.  I think you meant `i <= 51`?

Comment: Where does the second word of length 12 reside in `querySeq`? At what offset? Because that should be the values passed to `at()` when `i=1` and `j=0`, right? So I ask you again, what value are you passing to `at()` and what value _should_ you be passing?

Comment: the second word starts from the offset 1 to 12.  I pass the at(i +j ) for example for i=0 the j loop repeats 12 times from 0 to 11 to extract the first word.

Comment: no i meant  i<52 because the queryBlocksize is 52

Comment: I think the problem of my code is that at the of the querySeq array there is a "\n" character and that is why the last word is not included. how can I include that "\n" in the final word. I mean the last word's length is 11 not 12 because of this "\n".